# error accessing image, "file:///C:/Users/" not found

Tags: html, image

I made web site in html,but I have a problem when I click on some image in gallery, there is not new page.This is the error:

This webpage is not found
No webpage was found for the web address: file:///C:/Users/

Comment: You'll need to provide more information for an insightful answer. Can you provide us with the HTML for your question above?

Answer (score 0):

"file:///C:/Users/" means that you wrote one or more html links pointing to your local hard disk (whoops). You need to find those links and rewrite them as relative URLs. http://www.google.com/search?q=relative+url+absolute+OR+file